# Why find intersections does not work with THREE.UTF8Loader?

Tags: three.js

I clone https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js.git, and I did 2 changes for sample webgl_loader_utf8.html

1. Add CubeGeometry
2. Support find intersections

When I clicked Cubes can find intersections, but clicked utf8 models(for instance, ben or hand models) can't find intersections. Any ideas about this? Many thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>three.js webgl - io - UTF8 loader</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            body {
                font-family: Monospace;
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
                margin: 0px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            #info {
                color: #fff;
                position: absolute;
                top: 10px;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                z-index: 100;
                display:block;
            }
            #info a, .button { color: #f00; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="info">
        <a href="http://threejs.org" target="_blank">three.js</a> -
        <a href="http://code.google.com/p/webgl-loader/" target="_blank">UTF8 format</a> loader test -
        models from <a href="http://www.sci.utah.edu/~wald/animrep/" target="_blank">The Utah 3D Animation Repository</a>
        <div id="show"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/loaders/UTF8Loader.js"></script>
        <script src="js/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>

        <script src="js/Detector.js"></script>
        <script src="js/libs/stats.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/libs/tween.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            var SCREEN_WIDTH = window.innerWidth;
            var SCREEN_HEIGHT = window.innerHeight;

            var FLOOR = -150;

            var container, stats;

            var camera, scene, renderer;

            var projector, raycaster;
            var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

            var mesh, zmesh, geometry;

            var mouseX = 0, mouseY = 0;

            var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
            var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
            document.addEventListener( 'mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false );

            var show = document.getElementById("show");

            init();
            animate();


            function init() {

                container = document.createElement( 'div' );
                document.body.appendChild( container );

                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 20, SCREEN_WIDTH / SCREEN_HEIGHT, 1, 2000 );
                camera.position.z = 800;

                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                scene.fog = new THREE.Fog( 0x000000, 800, 2000 );

                var path = "textures/cube/SwedishRoyalCastle/";
                var format = '.jpg';
                var urls = [
                    path + 'px' + format, path + 'nx' + format,
                    path + 'py' + format, path + 'ny' + format,
                    path + 'pz' + format, path + 'nz' + format
                ];

                reflectionCube = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTextureCube( urls );

                // LIGHTS

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight( 0x222222 );
                scene.add( ambient );

                var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 1.1 );
                directionalLight.position.set( 0, 20, 300 );
                scene.add( directionalLight );

                directionalLight.castShadow = true;
                //directionalLight.shadowCameraVisible = true;

                directionalLight.shadowMapWidth = 2048;
                directionalLight.shadowMaHeight = 2048;

                var d = 150;

                directionalLight.shadowCameraLeft = -d * 1.2;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraRight = d * 1.2;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraTop = d;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraBottom = -d;

                directionalLight.shadowCameraNear = 200;
                directionalLight.shadowCameraFar = 500;


                // RENDERER

                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
                renderer.setSize( SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT );

                renderer.setClearColor( scene.fog.color, 1 );

                renderer.domElement.style.position = "relative";
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                //
/**
                renderer.gammaInput = true;
                renderer.gammaOutput = true;
                renderer.physicallyBasedShading = true;

                renderer.shadowMapEnabled = true;
                renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFShadowMap;
**/
                // STATS

                stats = new Stats();
                stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
                stats.domElement.style.zIndex = 100;
                container.appendChild( stats.domElement );

                var start = Date.now();

                var loader = new THREE.UTF8Loader();

                loader.load( "models/utf8/hand.js", function ( object ) {

                    var end = Date.now();
                    console.log( "hand", end - start, "ms" );

                    var s = 350;
                    object.scale.set( s, s, s );
                    object.position.x = 125;
                    object.position.y = -125;
                    //scene.add( object );

                    object.traverse( function( node ) {

                        node.castShadow = true;
                        node.receiveShadow = true;

                        if ( node.material && node.material.name === "skin" ) {

                            node.material.wrapAround = true;
                            node.material.wrapRGB.set( 0.6, 0.2, 0.1 );

                        }

                    } );

                }, { normalizeRGB: true } );

                loader.load( "models/utf8/ben_dds.js", function ( object ) {

                    var end = Date.now();
                    console.log( "ben", end - start, "ms" );

                    var s = 350;
                    object.scale.set( s, s, s );
                    object.position.x = -125;
                    object.position.y = -125;
                    scene.add( object );

                    object.traverse( function( node ) {

                        node.castShadow = true;
                        node.receiveShadow = true;

                        if ( node.material && ( node.material.name === "head" || node.material.name === "skinbody" ) ) {

                            node.material.wrapAround = true;
                            node.material.wrapRGB.set( 0.6, 0.2, 0.1 );

                        }

                    } );

                }, { normalizeRGB: true } );


                var geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 20, 20, 20 );

                for ( var i = 0; i < 20; i ++ ) {

                    var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial( { color: Math.random() * 0xffffff } ) );

                    object.position.x = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                    object.position.y = Math.random() * 800 - 400;
                    object.position.z = Math.random() * 800 - 400;

                    object.rotation.x = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                    object.rotation.y = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;
                    object.rotation.z = Math.random() * 2 * Math.PI;

                    object.scale.x = Math.random() + 0.5;
                    object.scale.y = Math.random() + 0.5;
                    object.scale.z = Math.random() + 0.5;

                    scene.add( object );

                }
                projector = new THREE.Projector();
                raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();


                //

                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

            }

            function onWindowResize() {

                windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
                windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

            }

            function onDocumentMouseMove( event ) {

                mouseX = ( event.clientX - windowHalfX );
                mouseY = ( event.clientY - windowHalfY );

                mouse.x = ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1;
                mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1;

            }

            //

            function animate() {

                requestAnimationFrame( animate );

                render();
                stats.update();

            }

            function render() {

                camera.position.x += ( mouseX - camera.position.x ) * .05;
                camera.position.y += ( - mouseY - camera.position.y ) * .05;

                camera.lookAt( scene.position );


                renderer.render( scene, camera );

            }


            function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

                event.preventDefault();
                                show.innerText = "";
                var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
                projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );

                var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( camera.position, vector.sub( camera.position ).normalize() );

                var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children );

                if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
                                   show.innerText = "intersects=" + intersects.length + " at " + Date.now();
                   console.log(intersects.length);

                }

            }

        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `recursive` flag to `raycaster.intersectObjects()`.

```
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children, true );
```

three.js r.58

Comment: Any other ideas? Thanks!
Below the version I used.
var THREE = THREE || { REVISION: '59' };

Comment: Use [r.60dev](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/build) plus my suggestion above. I have not been able to track down why this is not working in r.59, otherwise I would give you an explanation. Your code looks fine, and it does work in r.60dev.

Comment: Cool, you are right. I'm only update three.min.js, use "60dev" instead of '59'. Maybe there a bug with REVISION: '59'. 

Thanks very much.